# How can we read args using command line in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, command-line-arguments

I am passing a hard-coded `NSString` and converting to `NSArray`. Here I want to pass an `NSString` using command line and convert to an `NSArray`:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
NSArray*sampleMethod(NSString*val){
    NSString *newStr = [val substringFromIndex:1];
    NSString *newStr1 = [newStr substringToIndex:[newStr length]-1];
    NSString *trimmed = [newStr1 stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
    NSArray *yourWords = [trimmed componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
return yourWords;
}
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
        NSString *value =@"{1,2,3}";// hard code value
        NSArray* ip1= sampleMethod(value);
    /*
    NSArray* ip1= sampleMethod(argv[1]);
    here i want to read from command line and convert in to array
    */
        printf("output: %@ ",ip1);
    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The arguments passed to `main` are the values passed on the command line.

Comment: I am pass a string like {1,2,3,4} and i want to convert it into NSArray but i not get it by argv[1]... its give only first char...

Comment: Try this: NSArray* ip1= sampleMethod(@(argv[1]));

Comment: @NirbhavGupta `argv[1]` gives you a C string. You need to create an `NSString` from the C string.

Comment: @rmaddy No, you're wrong about @() creating an NSNumber. See http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html#boxed-expressions

Comment: @DamianCarrillo Very good. I admit I didn't know that wrapping a C string in `@()` created an `NSString`. Great to know. Thanks.

Comment: can you guys explain me how can i do this still stuck ....

Comment: @NirbhavGupta See the 1st comment by Damian.